# How does YouTube filter Pornography videos?

Tags: filter, youtube

Does they have good algorithm to detect porn via detecting skin Colors frame by frame or they have human intervention  ?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [Porn Video Classifier/Editor with Caffe](https://github.com/ryanjay0/miles-deep) which uses [Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning), is Open Source and seems well documented.